# Kubernetes: Error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to perform my first deployment of an application in a Kubernetes cluster in GCP.

I have the image of my application in Container Registration.

```
eu.gcr.io/diaphanum/bonsai-landing:v1
```

The manifest file I use is deploy-ironia.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bonsai-landing
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bonsai-landing
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bonsai-landing
spec:
  containers:
  - name: bonsai-landing
    image: "eu.gcr.io/diaphanum/bonsai-landing:v1"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

Use the following command to deploy from the GCP shell:

```
kubectl apply -f deploy-ironia.yaml
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: error validating "deploy-ironia.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError (Deployment.spec): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError (Deployment.spec) : "mandatory" field selector "is missing in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError (Deployment.spec): the mandatory field" template "is missing in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, disable validation with --validate = false
```

Any suggestions to solve it?

UPDATE:1

When run with --validate=false the message is:

```
The Deployment "landing" is invalid:
* spec.selector: Required value
* spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string(nil): `selector` does not match template `labels`
* spec.template.spec.containers: Required value
```

Comment: The second 'spec' is embedded within the template field. Have a look here for an example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment

Comment: Thanks, this resolve the  problem, the problema was the tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`deploy-ironia.yaml` file should be :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bonsai-landing
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bonsai-landing
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bonsai-landing
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: bonsai-landing
       image: "eu.gcr.io/diaphanum/bonsai-landing:v1"
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks, this resolve the problem, the problem is the tab.

Comment: The issue for me was the tab (indentation) as well. Thank you.