# Unable to create a cronjob in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to create a cronjob , I have written a Springboot application for this and have created a abc-dev.yml file for application configuration

error: unable to recognize "src/java/k8s/abc-dev.yml": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "apps/v1"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: abc-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          container:
          - name: abc-cron-job
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are running kubernetes 1.20 or lower, the correct apiVersion value is:

`apiVersion: batch/v1beta1`

If you are running kubernetes 1.21 or higher, its

`apiVersion: batch/v1`

Comment: Hi @Blender  i checked the version, it is  Dashboard v2.2.0+0.g0a30039e0. Still batch/v1 doesn't work

Comment: No no, that's not the kubernetes version. Run `kubectl version` -- you will get two lines - one for the client (your kubectl) and one for the server. The server version is what will determine what is supported.

Comment: where to run this kubectl version? i am referring https://k8s-dash-nonprod-ctc.mycompany.com/. it is not set up in my local

Comment: You run this locally, or from the machine where you are trying to run the deployment from.

Comment: Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.7", GitCommit:"abc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T12:32:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Is  GitVersion:"v1.20.7" i need to refer?

Comment: You are running 1.20 kubernetes. You should use `batch/v1beta1` for your cronjob

Comment: Yes i tried that and i am not getting that error anymore but ran into another error now error: error validating "src/java/k8s/abc-dev.yml": error validating data: [ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec): unknown field "container" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec, ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec): missing required field "containers" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Comment: let me try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027771/8274672

Comment: That is a deployment, not a cronjob.

Comment: I will replace the deplymnet with cronjob and other schedule and other value related to cronjob. Will that work?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: still getting same error apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: lab-aggregator-service-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          container:
          - name: lab-aggregator-service-cron-job
            image: docker.repo.abc.com/xyz-services/abc-application/REPLACE_ME
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242009/discussion-between-blender-fox-and-lucky).

Comment: For anyone coming to this later, the error was that OP was using "container" instead of "containers" in his spec.

Comment: apiVersion: batch/v1 works in Client Version: v1.28.6

Comment: @macosmi it will continue to work until Kubernetes decides to deprecate that API version

Answer (score 7):

You can check the api-version of a resource with the

> kubectl api-resources

command.
In this case:

> kubectl api-resources | grep cronjob | awk -v N=3 '{print $N}'

The output is 'batch/v1'.

Answer (score 2):

Cronjob belongs to batch/v1 k8s api. You should check api version before creating resources in any case they sometimes change.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: Hi i changed to batch/v1 from apps/v1. Still getting the same error error: unable to recognize "src/java/k8s/abc-dev.yml": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1"